# AS3 - how to stop moving stage if it reaches the edge of background

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using a sidescroller where the stage follows the player until the background reachs the edge.

But how do I make it so the background doesn't show the stage when touching the end of the background? Like when it reaches the near end, the stage needs to stop moving and the player needs to move to the end on it's own. That way the stage won't show when touching the edge of the sky.

I currently have a code for the stage following player, but confused on how to make the stage stop at the end or beginning of map.

```
x = -(player.x-stage.stageWidth/2)
```

Comment: if it is a sidescroller, why do you put stageHeight there?
isn't it should be stageWidth?

Comment: You say your moving the stage? Can't help you if you are doing such horrible thing.

Comment: Did you even understand my question? Are you just trolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

```
x = -(player.x-stage.stageWidth/2);
if (x < 0){
   x = 0;
} else if(x > stage.stageWidth){
   x = stage.stageWidth;
}
```

Or whatever values you will need to check as your edge cases.